# error C3203: 'OMSSPDisk' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Kty', expected a real type

Tags: c++, set

I'm using set with templates in c++:

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
class OMSSVDisk : public OMSSObjProperties<TKey,TValue>{
    set<OMSSPDisk> memberPDs;
};
```

This is giving error as mentioned in title at third line (set...) in above code.

OMSSObjProperties is as follows:

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
class OMSSObjProperties{
    string objTypeName;
    string objTypeID;
    string objID;
    map<TKey,TValue> objProperties;
public:
    string getObjTypeName();// returns objTypeName
    string getObjTypeID();// returns objTypeID
    string getObjID();// returns objID

    void setObjTypeName(const char*);// sets objTypeName
    void setObjTypeID(const char*);// sets objTypeID
    void setObjID(const char*);// sets objID

    map<TKey,TValue> getObjProperties();
    TValue getObjPropertyValue(TKey Key);
    void setObjProperty(TKey key,TValue Value);
    string removeProperty(TKey Key);
};
```

and OMSSPDisk is a class as follows:

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
class OMSSPDisk : public OMSSObjProperties<TKey,TValue>{
};
```

So question here is, can we use class name as template argument?
Please help me to sort out the error.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you `#include <set>`? Also please paste the full error (always).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `OMSSPDisk` is a template, you have to include the actual template parameters in the declaration of the set.

Perhaps

```
set<OMSSPDisk<TKey, TValue>> memberPDs;
```

You cannot have a set of templates, you have to specify one specific type.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several causes:

- failure to `#include <set>`
- not qualifying `set`: `std::set`
- the compiler doesn't see `OMSSPDisk`. Include the file where the `class` is defined (a forward declaration is not enough, you need a complete type).

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify `set` as `std::set` and make sure that the header `set` is included.

Comment: He's obviously `using namespace std;` judging from `map` and `string` (in a header no less...). The missing `#include` is probably the problem.

Comment: I already used "using namespace std;" in my code.. So I don't think any need of using std::set

Comment: @SethCarnegie Ah, missed that.

Comment: @NDThokare I hope you understand the implication of `using namespace std;` in headers. It is bad practice and can lead to unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you

```
#include <set>
```

and you're

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: It's probably not good to encourage `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your code

1) Header File

```
#include<set>
```

2) Namespace

```
using namespace std; // before main()
```

or

```
std::set<OMSSPDisk> memberPDs;
```